# How to set features when create HttpClient in a library project

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I was migrating a project(library) from framework461 to standard2.0.
Previously it looks like this to create a HttpClient and set features.

```
    public class HttpClientCreator
    {
        readonly List<Func<DelegatingHandler>> features = new List<Func<DelegatingHandler>>();
        public HttpClient Create()
        {
            var httpClient = HttpClientFactory.Create(httpMessageHandler, features.Select(feature => feature()).ToArray());
            return httpClient;
        }
    }
```

I have 2 questions:

1. it's not a web API so I cannot register httpclient and use httpfactory
2. i don't know how to set features when creating a client?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`HttpClientFactory` is available in the [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client) NuGet package. You should be able to use it to migrate this part of your code to .NET Standard 2.0 with minimal changes.